# add customerGroup to article with PUT call

Tags: shopware

Im trying to update my articles and add a excluded CustomerGroup.

Since the documentation is pretty bad for that part I try to find some more help here.

I put this `[] Object` to shopware for example

```
[data] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1460
        [mainDetailId] => 1460
        [supplierId] => 1
        [taxId] => 1
        [filterGroupId] => 1
        [name] => XXX
        [added] => 2018-01-26T00:00:00+0100
        [active] => 1
        [pseudoSales] => 0
        [changed] => 2018-02-09T15:22:35+0100
        [lastStock] => 1
        [mode] => 0
        [mainDetail] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1460
                [articleId] => 1460
                [...] => ...
            )
        [customerGroups] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                         [customerGroupKey] => EK
                    )

            )
    )
```

The important part is the [customerGroups] array which i add and which doesnt work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a customer group before you use the "groupKey", use "CustomerGroup" api resource for this (see /engine/Shopware/Components/Api/Resource/CustomerGroup.php).

Comment: I did it on my backend. So i know that the CustomerGroup with id = 1 is the one im searching for.